# R information extract from text Fax:(Number)

Tags: regex, r

In R I want to perform text analysis and find the fax numbers in the data. Apart from digit pattern match (It will not work here as phone number with similar styles are present) , I want to use some technique to extract the fax number from the text.
Patters are:

```
Fax (tab) : 9890000
Fax:89182828
Fax    : 65535933
FAX (+85) 0449 0279
Fax: (85) 6336 7926
Fax    :     65535933
```

**Input** :**ID:515** I have this problem with my machine. Please call me back with the solution.
 -

Regards,

```
Shiny,
 Tel: 65535933 
 Fax: 65938933
```

**Result** should be only the fax number not the telephone number. The fax number can be with all above patterns
 - ID 
 - 515
Fax - 65938933 .

Comment: What do you mean with patterns `ID - 515` ... Just look for fax, and match the patterns after it. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried some regex to do the same. ID 515 was just the result format. It can be only the fax numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example data you provided, this regular expression should work

```
test<-c("Fax \t : 9890000",
    "Fax:89182828",
    "Fax    : 65535933",
    "FAX (+85) 0449 0279",
    "Fax: (85) 6336 7926",
    "Phone: (85) 6336 7926",
    "Fax    :     65535933")

matches<-regexpr("fax\\s*:?\\s*(.*)",test, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
capmathces<-regcapturedmatches(test,matches)
faxnums<-unlist(lapply(capmathces, function(x) if (length(x)>0) x[1] else NA))
cbind(faxnums, test)

# Results:
#      faxnums           test                   
# [1,] "9890000"         "Fax \t : 9890000"      
# [2,] "89182828"        "Fax:89182828"         
# [3,] "65535933"        "Fax    : 65535933"    
# [4,] "(+85) 0449 0279" "FAX (+85) 0449 0279"  
# [5,] "(85) 6336 7926"  "Fax: (85) 6336 7926"  
# [6,] NA                "Phone: (85) 6336 7926"
# [7,] "65535933"        "Fax    :     65535933"
```

Here i'm using the helper function [regcapturedmatches](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321#file-regcapturedmatches) but you could also use the captured match data and extract it yourself as well.

You might have to customize this depending on how exactly you are feeding your raw data into this function. I'm not sure if you're passing a complete text string with embedded new lines or if your passing in a vector of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand how can I use regcapturedmatches in my code. Error: could not find function "regcapturedmatches". I called the code in my program. or read the code with a delim regcapturedmatches="\\code\\regcapturedmatches.R"

Comment: If you place that code in a file called `regcapturedmatches.R`, then you can load it with `source("regcapturedmatches.R")` By default it will look in your current working directory (see `getwd()`) so if you specify a relative path, it should be relative to the current working directory.

Comment: But this doesn't work in cases where there is text like "Hi My machine doesnt work. Regards, shiny,tel:900034,fax:900054plz call back.Home Phone:+9577777 Fax:9999999Thanks"

Comment: fax\\s*:?\\s*\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?\\s*\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)? this regex works

Comment: @user3619015 A regular expression is only as good as your test cases. It's not magic. You need to be clear about what you're searching for.